# Referencing to an iframe in vba

Tags: html, excel, vba

as my previous question doesnt fit anymore, im creating a new one.

I have the following code to open an window. in that windows i want to open the sorting "function" and then select which attribute to sort.

1. Page opening works

What doesnt work, is trying to address the attributes of the sorting drop down menu, so that it can select the right one. i always get `debug.print length = 0` in the last code line

The code:

```
Sub testalt()

Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim ie As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim enumm As String
Dim ifrm As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim selection As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

enumm = "E2711846"

Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "https://plm.corp.int:10090/enovia/common/emxFullSearch.jsp?pageConfig=tvc:pageconfig//tvc/search/AutonomySearch.xml&tvcTable=true&showInitialResults=true&cancelLabel=Close&minRequiredChars=3&genericDelete=true&selection=multiple&txtTextSearch=" & [enumm] & "&targetLocation=popup"

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop


Set HTMLDoc = ie.document
Set ifrm = HTMLDoc.frames(1).document
Set selection = ifrm.getElementsByTagName("select")
Debug.Print selection.Length

End Sub
```

This is the, i think, relevant html part of the opened page. Sry dont know how to copyit

this is the iframe, which is on the top

[image]

Comment: Is this the HTML code in your picture the HTML code of the URL in `ie.navigate` or is this the HTML code of your iframe?

Comment: This is part of the code i see when i navigate to  ie.navigate

Comment: Looking at your code, it looks like the `select` part is in the main htmldoc, not in the iframe. Check the `src` attribute. You can see it contains a url. Manually, copy/paste that url into a new window of your navigator, and check the HTML code.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns sorry i dont quite understand. could you go more into detail pleasE?. Oh sorry i didnt screenshot enough of the html. the iframe is one lvl above. so the select is part of an iframe

Comment: Ok now i understood what u are saying. copy/paste gives me a blank page with no html code at all

Comment: @DimitriosTop try `Set selection = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("select")` it looks like your `select` is in `HTMLDoc` not in `ifrm`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ please look at my question edit. i inserted a new image.

Comment: yes but the HTML code you show in the pictures is not the code **inside** the iframe it is the code of `ie.navigate` which is `HTMLDoc`. The HTML code you show is the code that embedds the iframe.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ ok but then why does it give me length of 0 ?

Comment: Because the `select` is not in your iframe. As I already said it looks to be in the document itself not in the frame `Debug.Print HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("select").Length`. If that doesn't work please show the HTML inside the iframe.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ please check new image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208114/discussion-between-dimitrios-top-and-p).

Comment: On the screenshot alone I see 3 iFrames. I'm sure the one you want to address doesn't have the index 0 from the main document, but at least index 0 in the first iFrame. But as I wrote in the other thread, don't post screenshots, post code snippets.

Comment: @Zwenn sry i dont know how. i managed to figure out the following, which seems to be working :
Set ifrm = HTMLDoc.frames(0).frames(1).document

but i still cant get anything out of my Set selection

Comment: I think it's something like this **Set ifrm = HTMLDoc.frames(0).document.frames(0).document** But I did never test something with nested iFrames. It can be that it doesn't work in one line of code.

Comment: @Zwenn i already got the frames part. My problem now is the Set Selection part to get to my dropdown table.

Comment: Try it with **Set selection = ifrm.getElementByID("sort_column_0")** instead of **Set selection = ifrm.getElementsByTagName("select")** If you get a runtime error you are in the wrong iFrame.